# Vector Projections Help

Tags: vectors

Draw diagrams to explain the answers to the following questions.

1. Is it possible to have a ↓ b = 0?
2. Is it possible to have a ↓ b undefined?
3. Is it possible to have a ↓ b = b ↓ a?
4. Explain why a ↓ c =  a ↓ (b ↓ c)

I know, that is not possible that a ↓ b = 0, how can I represent that in a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any diagrams aside from drawing the projections of various vectors, which would probably be easiest in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Assuming "$a \downarrow b$" is the projection of $a$ onto $b$ (or vice versa), then when it comes to number $1$, what if $a = (1, 0)$ and $b = (0, 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

1) It is possible if a=0
2) Yes if the magnitude of b is 0
3) Only when a=b
4)The projection is on two vectors with the same direction.